# Test apple push notifications to multiple devices

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I need to check apple push notifications to multiple devices. I am using JavaPNS and the push is working fine. But I have only one device token with me. How can I be sure that in real time (when there will be millions of device tokens - devices) , the push will work fine.

I already saw this:
     [load testing apple push notification server application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636526/load-testing-apple-push-notification-server-application)
 but am not sure that I understand it completely or for that matter is it the correct approach.

Comment: you cant! how do you like them iApples? You will have to trust that a core feature of the core product of the (sometimes) largest company in the world will work. It absolutely isn't your job to test APN. You can stub out JavaPNS and see how your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
    {
        self.mDeviceToken = deviceToken;

        //Removing the brackets from the device token
        NSString *tokenString = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];

        NSLog(@"Push Notification tokenstring is %@",tokenString);

    }
```

when you get the token you should send this token to your database using webservice. in that way you will get all the tokens who installed your app.

Comment: When you get all the token you only have to do a while or foor loop which will pick token one by one and send message . Thats it!

Comment: thanks. I know that, but i want to test it now before it goes to the app store. I do not have multiple device tokens now so how can I test it?

Comment: if you have millions of device token than my suggestion is that to use Urban airship.

Comment: You need orignal token , you cant test it by adding dummy device tokens . my suggestion is that to use Urban airship . it will also works when you have 10 millions users and it is very very quick

Comment: thanks for your answer but its not what I am looking for. I cannot use Urban airship.